# Unable to get Outlook App (Android) to connect to on-premise Exchange 2019

Tags: exchange, outlook

## Overview

I have an Exchange hybrid deployment, with one Exchange 2019 server on-premise and an EXO subscription. Our `autodiscover.domain.com` is pointing to our on-premise Exchange environment. As is `mail.domain.com`.

## Problem

I'm trying to configure the Outlook App on my Android phone, trying to connect to an on-premise mailbox and it is not working.

When I open the Android, I enter the users email address `susan.jenkins@domain.com`. Then, I choose `Exchange` for the mailbox type. Then, after entering the server details and my credentials, I get the following error:

```
Login Error

Please check your email and password and try again
```

## Troubleshooting done so far

With this being a hybrid environment I'm not sure where to go to get logs.  That said, below is the troubleshooting I've done so far:

1. Confirmed that inbound mail flow from external sources to `susan.jenkins@domain.com` works without issue.
2. Confirmed that outbound mail flow from `susan.jenkins@domain.com` works without issue.
3. Was able to successfully log in to OWA externally, from another network.
4. Confirmed that there are no firewall rules blocking access to the on-premise Exchange server.

## Question(s)

- Are there any logs I can grab from the Outlook Android app to troubleshoot? And, how do I do that?
- What should be my next steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some troubleshooting steps for your reference:

1. Does this issue only occur to one specific user or all users?
2. Check if you have enabled activesync for this user. [Resolution - Step 1: Confirm that ActiveSync is enabled for the user](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/mobile-device-cannot-connect-via-activesync#resolution---step-1-confirm-that-activesync-is-enabled-for-the-user)
3. [Resolution - Step 2: Confirm that the mobile device isn't blocked by an ActiveSync quarantine rule](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/troubleshoot/administration/mobile-device-cannot-connect-via-activesync#resolution---step-2-confirm-that-the-mobile-device-isnt-blocked-by-an-activesync-quarantine-rule)
4. Run [EXRCA](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/Eas/input) to test activesync and you will get more configuration details for further troubleshooting.
5. Check if this issue occurs to outlook for IOS?

Additional information for your reference and hope it help: [[Exchange] Why do I get the message "Please check your email and password and try again"?](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/-exchange-why-do-i-get-the-message-please-check-your-email-and-password-and-try-again-c847b315-e0fa-4abb-ac56-c2eb5feed475)